# Get true last hotfix installed

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to get   the last  'Security Update' installed  from a  list of networked  PC's
I'm using the  Get-HotFix function   with  a  few options and this works  except when  two  different hot fixes  where  updated  the same day.. example

**Evaluation Function**

```
(Get-HotFix -ComputerName $Client -Description 'Security Update' | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn)[-1]
```

**Result**

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4586863     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

**Full Hotfix List**

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
PC-W007  Update           KB4578974     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/23/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Update           KB4513661                          1/9/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4516115                          1/9/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Update           KB4517245                          1/9/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4528759                          1/9/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4561600     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/8/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4565554     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/8/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4569073     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/21/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4576751     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/18/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4577670     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/23/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4580325     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/23/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4586863     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4586786     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

**Desired result**

```
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4586786     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Note these two  results:  I need the last one

```
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4586863     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
PC-W007  Security Update  KB4586786     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

Full Script

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$(Get-location)\RESULTLOG-$(Get-date -Format "yyyyMMddTHHmmss").log"

Function Get-FileName{
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$Importfile = Get-FileName
$Clients = Get-Content $Importfile
Foreach($Client in $Clients){

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Client -Count 2 -Quiet) {

        try { 
            (Get-HotFix -ComputerName $Client -Description 'Security Update' | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn)[-1]
            "==============================================================================="
        }
        catch { 
            "$Client An error occurred." 
            "==============================================================================="
        }  
   }
    else{
        "$Client  >>>>>>>  not on line "
        "==============================================================================="
    }
 }
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: what version of PoSh do you need? v2 and v3 are quite a bit different ... [*grin*]

Comment: It seems the `Get-HotFix` cmdlet returns objects with property `InstalledOn` being a String without a true time part. There is also a property called `InstallDate`, which is a DateTime object, but I have never seen that actually have a value..

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I need  ver.3

Comment: @victorR - i see that you found a solution ... and posted it. great! [*grin*] since you don't need ps2, please remove that tag from your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I found  out a solution to  my issue, I changed  my evaluation function to this :

```
(Get-HotFix -ComputerName $Client -Description 'Security Update' | Select-Object -Last 1)
```